# Reduce size of Windows 7 system image backup?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-backup

The Windows C:/ partition is now almost a terabyte and normal Windows backup "system image" option wants to backup all of that space instead of just the base Windows files.
How can I make an image/restore point ignoring all the surplus files?

Comment: An image backup doesn't really deal with files.  It copies raw bits, preserving their location on the platters.  There's no interpretation of what those bits represent.

Answer (score 1):

A "System image" is an image of the whole system drive, you can't pick and choose which files are included.

From Microsoft: "[A system image is an exact copy of a drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-a-system-image)."

Perhaps check out these other SU questions:

- [Windows 7 Backup - Does the "system image" include all the files on my drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/230095/windows-7-backup-does-the-system-image-include-all-the-files-on-my-drive)
- [How do I exclude directories from my Windows 7 backup?](https://superuser.com/questions/232510/how-do-i-exclude-directories-from-my-windows-7-backup)